# Why mongostat executable file is missing from mongodb enterprise 4.4.0?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run `mongostat` executable.

```
anish@Anishs-MacBook-Pro bin % mongostat --port 27017
zsh: command not found: mongostat
```

Now, this command is not running as the executable file is missing.

**I don't know why the file is missing from mongodb enterprise directory.**

I tried to check the `bin` folder by `ls -l`.

```
anish@Anishs-MacBook-Pro bin % ls -l
total 507696
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anish  staff      7683 Jul 25 20:33 install_compass
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anish  staff  42305060 Jul 25 20:53 mongo
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anish  staff  41491680 Jul 25 20:53 mongocryptd
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anish  staff  60059940 Jul 25 20:52 mongod
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anish  staff  16257824 Jul 25 20:34 mongodecrypt
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anish  staff  16160244 Jul 25 20:53 mongokerberos
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anish  staff  37228776 Jul 25 20:38 mongoldap
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anish  staff  46408252 Jul 25 20:44 mongos
```

It's not there. Why is it missing or am I searching in the wrong place ?

Note : I downloaded mongodb enterprise server from here : https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database-tools are not included anymore in the server package.

Download them separately from [MongoDB Database Tools](http://mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools)

Comment: Thank you so much. :) The package contains all the executable files.